# Are there any other ways to effect "responsibility to protect" without a UN security council approval?

Tags: international, treaty

“Responsibility to protect” is a UN pledge against genocide, ethnic cleansing and crimes against humanity which allowed states to authorise force as a last resort against other states if those crimes aren't being prevented or are actively being done by a state. The UN security council has vetoed many resolutions enabling this. But is the only way to enforce this through the UNSC?

Answer (score 2):

The General Assembly can pass a resolution, and unlike Security Council resolutions, no nation has veto power. However, except in procedural matters where the resolution can bind the General Assembly, such resolutions are not binding on member states. They are considered to be "recommendations". [Chapter VII resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_VII_of_the_United_Nations_Charter) i.e. Security Council resolutions are binding. Enforcement requires assent by the Security Council.